# How to restart an AS Class animation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oop, air, program-entry-point

I want to remove and re-add/"restart" the Main class when it finishes animating. All of my animations are happening in Main and are added to the display tree inside Main. Program.as handles all this by adding/removing Main. How can I run the `finishNow()` function inside Main.as? It all works fine, except throws an error for `program.finishNow();`:

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

The .fla file:

Linked to Program.as.

The Program.as file:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Program extends MovieClip {


        public function Program() {

            startNow();
        }

        function startNow() {
            var run:Main = new Main(this);
            addChild(run);
        }

        function finishNow() {
            removeChild(run);
            var run:Main = new Main(this);
            addChild(run);
        }

    }

}
```

The Main.as file:

```
package {

    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {

        var stageHolder:Object;
        public var program:Program;

        public function Main(stageHolderTemp) {
            stageHolder = stageHolderTemp; 
            trace(stageHolder);

            someFunctionsThatDrawGraphics();
        }

        function callFinishFunction():void {
            // how to call finishNow() function from Program.as file here?
            program.finishNow();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix to `TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.` can be found below. Previously the class was pointing to a null object.

```
package {

    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {

        // var stageHolder:Object; <- REMOVE this line
        public var program:Program;

        public function Main(stageHolderTemp) {
            program = stageHolderTemp; // changed stageHolder to program
            trace(program); // changed stageHolder to program

            someFunctionsThatDrawGraphics();
        }

        function callFinishFunction():void {
            program.finishNow();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have your `run` variable class-wide, not function-wide.

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class Program extends MovieClip {
    var run:Main; // <- THIS line
        public function Program() {
            startNow();
        }
        function startNow() {
            run = new Main(this); // and no 'var' here
            addChild(run);
        }
        function finishNow() {
            removeChild(run);
            run = new Main(this); // also no 'var' here
            addChild(run);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even when it's global (I've copy & pasted your code), it still shows up with the same error?

Comment: @ArrayOutOfBounds, Vesper's answer is correcting at least one issue. In the original code, the `run` variable in the `finishNow()` method should have been null. That method is so short, it's hard to see why the "null object reference" error would still occur, it doesn't make sense on the other 2 lines of that method :) I suggest you install the debug Flash Player, with that the error message will give you the line/frame number for where the problem is occurring, then you can confirm exactly where the issue is.

Comment: @ArrayOutOfBounds Oh, I think both Vesper and I may have misunderstood your comment about where the error is occurring. Like I said, he pointed out another problem. But before it gets there, the error is thrown in the `callFinishFunction()` method inside `Main.as`. The same issue is happening there. `Main.as` has a `program` variable, but it never gets set and is null. The program variable and the `stageHolder` variable are redundant. To fix, keep Vesper's fix and then remove `stageHolder` and do `program=stageHolderTemp` in the constructor for `Main.as`.

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly now. I've updated the answer with this solution. :)